# Sorry, this page isn't available in instagram

Tags: instagram-api

I am having difficulty in getting the latest post in **Instagram**.

```
function fetchData($url){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{clientid}/media/recent/?access_token={accesstoken}&count=3");

$result = json_decode($result);
```

But I get the message like this:

> Sorry the page is not available. The link you followed may be broken,
>   or the page may have been removed.

Comment: Go to that URL in the browser. What happens?

Answer (score 6):

Usually happens if you have `username` instead of `user-id` in the API url

you have `{clientid}`, what is the value?, it should be `user-id` not a `username`, and definitely not your app's `client-id`, it should be all numbers.

You can get `user-id` by using the users/search URL

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token={Access_token}
```

API to search for a username and get the corresponding `user-id` that matches the username you searched in the API response.

Comment: yes. when i changed the client id to userid, the issue is siolved. thanku.